# Why can't I access symfony session variables from other files?

Tags: php, session, symfony, session-variables

I have an web app built with symfony framework.

I want to merge an symfony app and an codeigniter app without creating a new application using only one framework. So if the user is loged in in symfony it will also be loged in codeigniter

Now i am just trying to access session variables of this symfony app from another php file, but the `$_SESSION` varible is empty.

(When I print it in this new file, when I print it in symfony files 'controllers, or views' printing it shows session variables correctly).

This `newfile.php` is in the same domain with symfony app,in the same folder with symfony's `index.php`, `admin.php`.

Can anybody help me do this?

Comment: Are both session cookies configured the same way? Are they using the same session storage mechanism?

Comment: Yes there are. I did `session_start(); `  and than `$_SESSION['sesname']='sesvalue';` , than tryied to access this file in the other php file. But the session variable is set inside symfony, and i think symfony changes the $_SESSION variable.

Symfony also has an configuration file were stores an path for sessions...

Answer (score 0):

For Symfony2 when using "composer" the solution is

```
require_once 'PATH_TO_LIB/vendor/autoload.php';
$symfonySession = new \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session($app['session.storage']);
$symfonySession->has('someVariable');
...
```