# Symfony2 and JS ajax call

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, symfony, session

I have a controller in my Symfony2 app where I set some value into the session with the following:

```
$token = '12345';
$session = $this->container->get('session');
$session->set('token', $token);
//var_dump($_SESSION);
```

Then in my JS code I POST some JSON data to my external `api.php` file which is not associated with Symfony framework. The problem is when I try to `var_dump` the contents of `$_SESSION` `superglobal` array from my external `api.php` file it is empty, though `var_dump($_SESSION)` from Symfony controller correctly shows all data stored in current `$_SESSION`. Any ideas how to fix that?

Comment: are you using the same session cookie name for both applications?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20858769/access-symfony-session-values-from-external-application

Comment: I just need to access my variable in session, though my user is simply ROLE_USER. Do I really need to load all the Symfony kernel stuff as described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27209315/5316626). Cant I do just like [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14804250/5316626)?